# Given an imported dataset, how do I assign the value of 0 to a new column if a value of a previous column = 1? On R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, equation

I'm a beginner to R so please excuse me if this is an overly simple question.

With n-back data, I'm trying to calculate the bias of the one-back trials.

I imported a dataset from Excel to R successfully and everything works except for the line

```
if (df$one_back_aprime == 1) {
  df$one_back_bias <- 0
}
```

in the following code:

```
library(readxl)
nback_mornings_data <- read_excel("NFS4and5_mornings_R.xlsx", sheet = 1) #replace with file name
df <- data.frame(nback_mornings_data)

if (df$one_back_hit_rate > df$one_back_fa_rate) {
  df$one_back_aprime <- 0.5 + ((df$one_back_hit_rate - df$one_back_fa_rate) * (1 + df$one_back_hit_rate - df$one_back_fa_rate))/(4 * df$one_back_hit_rate * (1 - df$one_back_fa_rate))
  } else if (df$one_back_hit_rate < df$one_back_fa_rate) {
    df$one_back_aprime <- 0.5 + ((df$one_back_fa_rate - df$one_back_hit_rate) * (1 + df$one_back_fa_rate - df$one_back_hit_rate))/(4 * df$one_back_fa_rate * (1 - df$one_back_hit_rate))
  } 

if (df$one_back_aprime == 1) {
  df$one_back_bias <- 0
} else {
  df$one_back_bias <- (((1 - df$one_back_hit_rate) * (1 - df$one_back_fa_rate)) - (df$one_back_hit_rate * df$one_back_fa_rate)) / (((1 - df$one_back_hit_rate) * (1 - df$one_back_fa_rate)) + (df$one_back_hit_rate * df$one_back_fa_rate))
}
```

When I run the code, everything works, except when the one_back_aprime == 1 , it prints NaN (because that's what the equation at else churns out). 
However, I'm confused as to why this is because I already put that it should be assigned the value of 0. So clearly I'm doing that wrong.
Can anyone please help to change that portion of the code so that when one_back_aprime = 1, the new one_back_bias column will show the value of 0? Note: I've tried print("0") but that doesn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated! 
I'm sure I'm missing something very basic, but again, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: `if` statements only take in one element eg `if(letters[1] == "a"){}`. It should be throwing you a lot of warnings if your data set has more than one row e.g. `if(letters == "a"){}` should throw the warning `Warning message: In if (letters == "a") { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. I'd recommend reading some tutorials on data wrangling or data manipulation from google searches eg https://ourcodingclub.github.io/tutorials/data-manip-intro/

Comment: Ran out of space. Typically the syntax for data.frames is `df[df$column_a > x, ]$column_b <- y` so you do the logic condition inside of the data frame rather than use `if` statements. This eg translates to if `column_x` is greater than a value `x` which could be eg `df$column_c` then replace `column_b` with some value(s) `y`. I'd suggest start with online tutorials though to understand the syntax of working with data.frames. Alternatively a lot of people start by learning dplyr eg http://ohi-science.org/data-science-training/dplyr. It takes some time though

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will give it a go and read through those links. @JonnyPhelps

Comment: It all works now, thanks for your help again @JonnyPhelps